# Como colocar uma imagem no site através de link

Tags: javascript, html

Onde está o erro aqui? Gostaria que a imagem aparecesse dentro desse box que criei.

[box http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000158-545b055540/Teste_leandro.png](http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000158-545b055540/Teste_leandro.png)

Comment: O que aparece no console?

Comment: Desculpe, console onde? O código não seria esse <div class="box_escudo" </div>
   <div class=""escudo" files.saichorao.com.br/200000156-3b01b3c582/testeimagem.jpg" </div>

Answer (score 1):

Não sei bem se o box que você montou tinha esse objetivo
Mas ha alguns erros no código `HTML` que você passou por comentário, tags não fechadas e a imagem com o source na div(?)

O correto seria algo do tipo:

```html
<div class="box_escudo">  <div class="escudo" ><img src="http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000156-3b01b3c582/testeimagem.jpg"/> </div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode passar um caminho dos diretórios do servidor até a imagem ou diretamente a URL da imagem, por exemplo:

Caminho no HD:

```
<img src="C:/imagem.jpeg" alt="imagem" />
```

URL da internet:

```
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" alt="Smiley" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido... Quando criei o box em css, deixei em branco, e o correto era ter colocado o link lá.

```
.escudo
        { width:128px; height:128px; background: url("http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000156-3b01b3c582/testeimagem.jpg") center no-repeat;}
```